# smtp gateway sending to 3rd party

Tags: email, meteor

The users of this Meteor app need to send email to their customers. The code to do that is simple:

```
Email.send({
     to: customerEmailAddress,
     from: userEmailAddress,
     subject: 'someSubject',
     html: html
});
```

However since each user has a different `userEmailAddress`, AWS is rejecting the sending:

> 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified.

It is not easy to verify each and every user email on AWS, and not sure if all other smtp server would give the same response, Any suggestions on how to handle this error for current and future users, which could be few hundred of them, each uses own domain, and each has own clients? thx

Comment: UserEmailadress it's all in the same domain?

Comment: No. each user has his own domain